# Counting the number of words in all lines in shell script

Tags: bash

My aim to count the number of words in a file

My input file is below :

```
100,Surender,CTS
101,Kumar,TCS
102,Raja,CTS
103,Vijay,TCS
```

The expected answer is 12

The shell script that I wrote for this is below

```
let total_no_of_words=0;
while read each_line ;

do

   words=`echo $each_line | tr "," " " |wc -w`
   total_no_words=`expr $total_no_words + $words`

done < /home/user/surender/linux/inputfiles/records.txt;

echo $total_no_of_words
```

But as Per above script the output that I get is 0.
if I keep the variable $total_no_words inside while loop then it gives cumulative word count such as 3 6 9 12

What do I need to do to get output as 12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo

```
total_no_of_words=`expr $total_no_of_words + $words`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F, '{n+=NF}END{print n}' file
```

I'm using `,` as the field delimiter (*word* delimiter in your context) and add the number of words for each line to the variable `n`. Once all lines have been processed I print the value of `n`.

---

I would use awk here but just out of curiosity, if you want to use `wc` for counting words, I would use `grep` to put every word on a single line and count the lines:

```
grep -o '[^,]\+' file | wc -l
```

Also you've asked how to do that using a while loop. You can do it like this:

```
while read word ; do
    n=$((n+1))
done < <(grep -o '[^,]\+' file)
echo "$n"
```

But anyhow, use awk! :)

Comment: ok. Is it possible to achieve the same word count with the help of while loop.. I am just starting my learning on Linux ,hence asked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`

```
cat your_file.txt | sed 's/[[:punct:]]\+/\n/g' |wc -l
12
```

your_file.txt

```
100,Surender,CTS
101,Kumar,TCS
102,Raja,CTS
103,Vijay,TCS
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of simplifying your script is to read each line into an array, and just sum the resulting array lengths.

```
total_no_of_words=0
while read -a each_line; do
    (( total_no_of_words += ${#each_line[@]} ))
done < /home/user/surender/linux/inputfiles/records.txt;

echo $total_no_of_words
```